# Connecting MYSQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, cpanel

i have a localhost instance of a web app that runs fine using MAMP.  But when I upload the files and the database to godaddy cPanel, I get a connectin error.  I can duplicate the error on MAMP by changing the DB credentials.

This is a new shared hosting account that i just setup so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot the issue. (Bottom block of code)

I originally had this deployed on AWS, which worked fine.  However I didn't originally setup the server configuration. (top block of code)

I'm guessing that the $dbhost doesn't know where to locate the DB.  Do I need to create an A record pointing to all DB instances?  How do I get what originally worked on AWS and currently works on local install of MAMP, to work on my new Godaddy setup?

I appreciate any responses.

```
//Credentials for AWS
// $dbhost = 'localhost';
// $dbuser = 'userDB';
// $dbpass = 'CjhkM..6gjj_interf';
// $dbname = 'sampleDB';

//Credentials for development on my computer
//**This worked on localhost with MAMP
// $dbhost = 'localhost';
// $dbuser = 'root';
// $dbpass = 'root';
// $dbname = 'sampleDB';

//Credentials for Godaddy Server Instance
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'aquaNot';
$dbpass = '#7GUq3433434223445hfs_b4![z_I';
$dbname = 'sampleDB';
```

Comment: Did you create the database and database user using the cPanel interface? I am not sure if those are dummy values for SO but the database name and database user do not look like they were created via cPanel.

Comment: Umm, hello Ruby, you see the problem here is that you haven't provided the `$dbhost` of the server running your files on godaddy. Local host indeed works for local use, but when you upload something on the internet, things get a little more strictly organised.

Comment: Both responses were correct, much appreciated!  I deleted my existing DB and started over.  I created a new database and a user through the cPanel interface. HOWEVER, I completely forgot to assign the user to the database and assign permissions.  I corrected this the second time around, which solved my problem!